# How to publish oracle db layer with geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I use geoserver version 2.18.4.

And I created a store and connected the oracle db.

However, there is no geometry column in my oracle table.

I have x column and y column of latitude and longitude coordinate system.

How do I publish a layer when there is no geometry column and only has x and y coordinate columns?

If there is only x-coordinate column and y-coordinate column, I am trying to publish a layer through sql view, but how do I set the geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to somehow provide a Geometry column before GeoServer will consider your table.

You could create a view which generates a geometry on the fly, but this is likely to be slow for any reasonable size of data and may lead to problems with metadata.

A better solution is to add a column to your table and populate it directly using the values in the latitude and longitude columns.